# Fetching longitude and latitude in background using Async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps, location, android-gps

I want that user presses button, after pressing button gps should fetch coordinates automatically in background, as you know gps may take some minutes to fetch coordinates, i just want thet gps take its time and after fetching coordinates then execute a method named 'SendLocationSms',

if i use onLocationChanged method in doInBackground it gives an error,
or if i fetch coordinates without using async task, then i have to wait for coordinates, and after fetching i can press the button to execute method SendLocationSms,

i want that user just have to press a button while gps is on, then gps take time as much it needed to fetch coordinates, after fetching then automatically run my desired method without noticing the user.

Basicly i am developing an app which send user's location via sms on pressing alert button, user just have to turn on gps and press alert button nd app should do the rest, i dont want that user wait till gps to fetch coordinates to send alert.

please help me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {


private LocationManager n;
private double lat;
private double lot;
private Button save;

private TextView textSMS;
private String gps;
private String sms;
public Button con;
DatabaseHelper myDb;

String id, cell1;




protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    con = (Button) findViewById(R.id.con);
    con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contacts.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);



    Cursor c = myDb.getAllData();
    c.moveToFirst();
    cell1 = (c.getString(1));



    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    textSMS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

    textSMS.setText("Help me please im at: [location]");
    sms="Help me please im at: ";







    n = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    n.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 100, this);


    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if ( gps != null ) {



                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(cell1.toString(), null, sms + gps, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your message sent successfuly !",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS failddddd!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location l) {

    this.lat=l.getLatitude();
    this.lot=l.getLongitude();
    this.gps = "\n" +
            "www.google.com/maps/place/"+lat+","+lot;

    TextView locc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locc);
    locc.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    locc.setText("New Location Fetched !");




    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();








        }






@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Gps enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned off!! ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



}

public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
```

}

listen, on clicking the button from activity, i want to send longitude and latitude by sms, i turn on gps, and press button, but u know gps takes a minute or two to fetch coordinates, so if i press button before getting coordinates ofcourse it will send null as latitude and longitude, so i want that if still gps not got coordinates but user pressed the button, then app shoild wait until location fetched and then send sms containing of latitude and longitude. so this is detail :) hope now u can help me , thanks alot

Comment: You can use an IntentService

Comment: please tell me in detail if u can i am new to android

Comment: If you really need to do this in background an intent service has access to everything accessible via activity and it works in your background. But the real question here why would you need to do this operation in the background? You can put your code in onLocationChanged directly or in onConnected

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi i want to send location via sms if user presses the alert button, not evry time when location fetched, :) please tell solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity you need to record the current location.

```
...
private Location currentLocation;   
...

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {      

    currentLocation = location;     

}
```

You can now use this variable in your asyncTask when the user will click on send location via sms.

And don't forget somewhere in your code to request location updates as an example look at this:

```
LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()  // LocationRequest parameters definition.
        .setInterval(30000)         
        .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

if(googleApiClient.isConnected()){ 
           LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, REQUEST, this);
}
```

**EDIT:**
You can the following. Add a boolean that notify that the user want to send current location and when the location is ready, you can send it. So you will have to modify your onclick listener and the location update listener in this way:

```
...
private boolean needSendSMS = false;
...

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if ( gps != null ) {
            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(cell1.toString(), null, sms + gps, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your message sent successfuly !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS failddddd!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        else{
            needSendSMS = true;
        }

    }

...
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {      

    this.lat=l.getLatitude();
    this.lot=l.getLongitude(); 
    if ( needSendSMS) {
        needSendSMS=false;
        // Send your sms like you did before.
    }      

}
```

Comment: If it is not clear please post your code so we can help by pointing where you should add modify code.

Comment: but i want to send longitude and latitude separately in sms, how can i get longitude and latitude from this variable

Comment: currentLocation.getLatitude(); and
  currentLocation.getLongitude();

Comment: In your asynktask you should do the necessary for that but the latitude and longitude will be available to you since currentLocation will be an attribute of your activity.

Comment: Ok dear JAWAD listen, on clicking the button from activity, i want to send longitude and latitude by sms,
i turn on gps, and press button, but u know gps takes a minute or two to fetch coordinates,
so if i press button before getting coordinates ofcourse it will send null as latitude and longitude,
so i want that if still gps not got coordinates but user pressed the button, then app shoild wait until location fetched and then send sms containing of latitude and longitude.
so this is detail :) hope now u can help me , thanks alot

Comment: and i want to do this without internet, only by GPS itself, and gps takes time sometime in my house it takes more than three minutes.

Comment: Ok i understand now. Show me what you have so far and we can work it out.

Comment: it works simply if i wait till gps fetch locatiuon and after knowing that coordinates fethced then i press button and it send in sms, but i press button before gps got the coordinates then it sends null as coordinates

Comment: what is diffirence between 
if ( needSendSMS) { }  and  if ( needSendSMS = true) { }  
:)

Comment: You meen needSendSMS == true... It is exactly the same. If needSensSMS is true the expression needSendSMS == true is equal to true. and if needSendSMS is false the epression needSendSMS == true is equal to false so at the end it is exactly the same.

Comment: You can always use boolean values in if statement without explicitly equate them to true or false...